# Как оптимальней реализовать AJAX-загрузку

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, yii2

Есть форма, содержимое которой, естественно, отправляется на сервер. В ответ сервер выдает данные, которые JS должен преобразовать в файл и отдать на загрузку (`Blob`). Каким способом лучше всего реализовать.

1. Два AJAX-запроса на сервер. Один возвращает данные. Другой - представление (`view`) страницы с кнопкой загрузки.
2. Грузим кнопку загрузки сразу на страницу и, после получения данных с сервера, просто показываем ее.
3. Получаем данные с сервера и рисуем кнопку средствами JS.

Сам склоняюсь к третьему, он более лаконичный. Но вроде как смешивать код с разметкой не гуд?

P.S. Использую YII2. Под `view` подразумевается просто див с кнопкой, подгружающийся в неизменный шаблон.

Comment: Вы не могли бы более подробно описать ваш пример. В идеале на приведите реальную задачу, которую вы пытаетесь решить. Я так понимаю вы реализовываете rest api на сервере?

Comment: Нет, не rest api. Реальная задача состоит в том, чтобы сгенерировать текстовый файл и отдать его на скачку. Все. Больше ничего. Просто чтобы снизить нагрузку на сервер было решено отдать генерацию файла на клиент.

Comment: Вы не могли бы уточнить как вы собираетесь генерировать файл на клиенте?

Comment: Я уже написал. Через Blob. Можно и через data:uri, но это уж слишком костыльно.

Comment: Если ТЗ позволяет использовать Blob, то естественно первый вариант отпадает как самый медленный (два http запроса). Далее, нужно отталкиваться от удобства пользовательского интерфейса. В последнем варианте, если я правильно понимаю, есть вероятность того, что кнопка никогда не появится, что не очень хорошо. Нужно дать понять пользователю, что идет загрузка документа сразу, а потом по мере возможности обновлять статус. Значит из ваших трех остается второй.

Comment: Ну иконка ожидания, конечно, будет. Как и сообщения об ошибках. Как же без них. Вопрос только в том, как красивее реализовать - генерить разметку в JS при необходимости. Или грузить со страницей сразу, а потом показывать-скрывать.

Comment: Очевидно, что красивее/логичнее грузить со сраницей сразу. Такое количество кода не повлияет существенно на размер страницы, но поможет при отлавливании ошибок в будущем.

Comment: Ну вот. Значит второй вариант :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ничего плохого в скрытии/открытии функционала шаблона по событиям нет. Вы можете обернуть в скрытый div и показывать кнопки после получения ajax. Саму верстку можно на уровне шаблона сделать и не примешивать её в js. Также генерация файлов на js - плохой путь. Передавайте только содержимое файла а на бекенде уже смотрите в сторону file_put_conents("file.txt", $content) на php

Comment: А что плохого в генерации на клиенте? Файлы простейшие. Весом максимум (в каком-то невероятном случае) до 100 килобайт. Обычно 10-15. Реализовав таким образом я полностью передаю файл в руки пользователю. Пусть качает, пусть не качает. Пусть оставит вкладку открытой и хранит ее месяц. Плюс сервер не выполняет лишних действий, не забивается всяким хламом, не хранит ничего. Только отдает.

P.S. Я генерирую файл не для отправки на сервер. А, наоборот, из ответа сервера. Для скачивания.

Comment: Все зависит от вашей бизнес задачи. Если это второстепенная функция интерфейса. Вас особо не заботит работа в старых браузерах а также вы не переживаете, за мобильные устройства - то вполне можно. Я на вашем месте возвращал бы с сервера уже готовые ссылки на сгенерированные файлы, а самим файлам на сервере оставил бы срок жизни 1-2 часа после генерации.

Comment: За старые браузеры не переживаю. На мобильных - буду тестить. Вроде там не все так плохо. А генерацию на бэкенде оставлю как запасной вариант.